# Implementing the "highlight effect" instead of the "ripple effect" to a custom button when tapped on Android and iOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom button in my `Xamarin.Forms` application created by inheriting the `ContentView` class and am looking to implement the "highlight effect" similar to that of the iOS platform(as seen in the image) when this custom view is tapped.

[image: highlight effect demonstration]

I am aware that, on the Android platform, the Android specific ripple effect can be implemented in a custom view by creating a custom renderer specific to the custom view and adding the `RippleDrawable` object to the native control as follows:

```
class CustomButtonRenderer
            : ViewRenderer
                <CustomButton,
                 Android.Views.View>
    {
        public DescriptiveButtonRenderer(Context context)
                : base(context)
        { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomButton> e)
        {
            LayoutInflater viewInflater;
            Android.Views.View view;
            GradientDrawable drawnBackground;
            StateListDrawable drawableStateList;
            RippleDrawable drawableRippleEffect;

            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control == null)
            {
                // Implement the Android specific resource pertaining to
                // the Android specific XML layout of the custom button
                viewInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.Context
                                .GetSystemService(
                                  Context
                                    .LayoutInflaterService);
                view = viewInflater.Inflate
                                     (Resource.Layout.CustomButton,
                                     null,
                                     false);

                // For ripple effect
                drawnBackground = new GradientDrawable
                                   (GradientDrawable.Orientation.LeftRight,
                                    new int[] {
                                    this.Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid(),
                                    this.Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid()
                                    });
                drawableStateList = new StateListDrawable();
                drawableRippleEffect = new RippleDrawable
                                        (ColorStateList.ValueOf
                                            (Android.Graphics.Color.White),
                                         drawnBackground,
                                         null);
                drawableStateList.AddState
                                   (new int[] {
                                       Android.Resource
                                         .Attribute.StateEnabled },
                                       drawableRippleEffect);
                view.Background = drawableStateList;

                this.SetNativeControl(view);
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, a similar approach to the above solution cannot be used as there is no class that facilitates the "highlight effect" in the API libraries.

I am also aware that, in the Android platform, the ripple effect can be removed from a Button by implementing a custom render similar to the one bellow, which sets a `null` value to the `StateListAnimator` property of the native control as follows:

```
class ButtonCustomRenderer
            : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public ButtonCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // Remove the ripple effect
            if (this.Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                    this.Control.StateListAnimator = null;
                else
                    this.Control.Elevation = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the hopes of using the above approach, I looked into the inbuilt animators pertaining to the type `Android.Animation.StateListAnimator` but could not find any that fulfilled the requirement.

My initial, and only, intuition regarding the solution to this problem was to manually alter the background color of the view to a "highlighted color" when the view is pressed or tapped, but, I believe, this is not an elegant solution as it is extremely strenuous to emulate the native "highlighted color" from the background color of the custom button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Android,you just need set the button backgroud with a selector animation.

create a **highlightbutton.xml** in your `Resources/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!--press-->
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
     <shape >
       <solid android:color="#c00"/>
     </shape>
   </item>

   <!--normal-->
   <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="false">
      <shape >
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
      </shape>
   </item>
</selector>
```

then in your customrenderer :

```
class ButtonCustomRenderer
          : ButtonRenderer
{
    public ButtonCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.highlightbutton);
        }
    }
}
```